# AngularJS update value from AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I'm updating scope value directly, it updates in view just fine, but when this value is updated from AJAX callback it doesn't update. Here is simplified example - http://jsfiddle.net/hS8Bs/1/

How can I get around it?

**Update:** I noticed that clicking second time on the link does update the value, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hS8Bs/3/ This is also a possible solution. But the other solution mentioned below which uses a $http is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The real problem is the lack of `$scope.$apply`. When you are updating the angular model outside of the angular digest you should use apply.

```
$.getJSON('/echo/json/', {}, function(data){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.period = '2010 - 2011';
    });
});
```

This will trigger the diggest to see the update and if your code inside of apply throw an exception it will be redirected to the `$exceptionHandler` service.

Comment: `$scope.$apply` is exactly what I have been looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is an addon to the selected answer, I found that Angular JS still called "Error: $digest already in progress" when I implemented the $apply() function.

So I found [Will Vincent's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1972101/will-vincent) code on this post:
[AngularJS : What's the Angular way to interact with a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448386/angularjs-whats-the-angular-way-to-interact-with-a-form)
, it checks for $digest already in progress and only calls $apply() when safe to:

```
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
          fn();
        }
    } else {
       this.$apply(fn);
    }
};
```

so it would be something like:

`$scope.safeApply(function() { ...code here... });`

Answer (score 3):

Here is your [missing tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) you need to use $http parameter of controller in order to get field updated.
Check your updated example http://jsfiddle.net/hS8Bs/2/